# How To Read JSONObject In Android

Tags: android-studio

Iam new to android and trying to read Json name/value pairs under the JsonProperty(enad_list) in android studio.

For example in the Json below i want to read the name, address, dob, expiry values. Please anyone guide, thanks.

```
{"enad_list":[{"name":"My name","Address":"My Address","dob":"16-11-1991","expiry":"2025-09-14"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it by using the following code. Posting here if it helps someone.

```
try {

                String Lastest = null;
                JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("enad_list");

                for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    gt_name = jsonObject.optString("name").toString();
                    gt_cnic = jsonObject.optString("cnic").toString();
                    gt_dob = jsonObject.optString("dob").toString();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 classes called Enad and EnadList

```
public class EnadList {

private List<Enad> enadList;
 // getters and setters here
}
```

the second class

```
public class Enad {

private String name ;
private String Address ;
private String dob ;
private String expiry ;
 // getters and setters here
}
```

Then to retrieve values do this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

EnadList enadList = gson.fromJson(jsonstring, EnadList.class);
//do something with your list
// Enad enad=enadList.get(0);
// enad.getName();
```

where jsonstring is a string equal to {"enad_list":[{"name":"My name","Address":"My Address","dob":"16-11-1991","expiry":"2025-09-14"}]}